# ayuda ficheros en C

Tags: c, archivo

Nesecito crear un programa que escriba un archivo de `bytes`, con el nombre que se le ingrese, con un número y preguntar si ese numero es `Mb` o `Gb` y ya tengo el siguiente codigo desarrollado, aunque creo que no es la mejor manera de hacerlo por que el archivo que se genere debe de contener "0xAA" que son 01, la verdad no se como escribir este tipo de dato...

con el for hago que lo que cadena que imprimo se escriba "x" veces para llegar al maño deseado

```
for (i=0; i<=((529000)*numero*1000);i++)
```

en lugar de imprimir

```
fprintf(fichero, "%s","01");
```

pero quisiera saber como imprimir algo parecido a esto:

```
  memset(*buffer, 0xaa, 1024);
```

o esa es mi duda es la mejor manera la mas optima imprimir "x" veces la cadena paa que el archivo que se cree tenga el tamaño especificado?

Comment: No entiendo lo que intentas escribir en el archivo. Explicate mejor, a ver que se puede hacer.

Comment: ya edite la pregunta a ver si se entiende un poco mas

Comment: Ok. Respuesta actualizada.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo de escribir en el archivo, no entiendo lo que quieres decir, pero lo del if es simple:

En C, una cadena es un **puntero** a una cadena; al hacerlo así

```
if( nombre1 == "mb" ) { ...
```

en realidad estas comparando 2 **punteros**, que no te van a coincidir.

Tienes que usar la función `strcmp( )`, que hace precisamente eso, comparar cadenas. Sería algo como

```
if( ! strcmp( nombre1, "mb" ) )
```

o

```
if( strcmp( nombre1, "mb" ) == 0 )
```

`strcmp( )` devuelve **0** si las cadenas son iguales.

**EDITO**

No me fijé. Lo anterior te dara fallo. Has hecho

```
char nombre1[2];
```

En C, las cadenas se terminan con un **byte** **0** (que tu no ves). Entonces, necesitas `nombre1[3];`scanf( )` añade el **0** automaticamente al final de la cadena.

**EDITO 2**

Para imprimir, vas bién. Te falta afinar:

```
char Buffer[1001]; // Fíjate en que dejo espacio para el 0 final.
Buffer[1000] = 0; // Ponemos nosotros el 0. Los índices empiezan en 0 también.

memset( Buffer, 0xAA, 1000 ); // Descontamos el espacio extra para el 0.
// NO *Buffer. Solo Buffer.

fprintf( fichero, "%s", Buffer );
```

Con `fprintf( ... "%s" ... )` indicas que vas a *imprimir* una cadena de texto **terminada en 0**. **0xAA** **no** es cero, asi que colocamos nosotros un 0 al final, y lo mandamos imprimir.

Puedes *imprimir* el mismo buffer todas las veces que quieras.